# The concept groupwin is like the unaligned windows?

Tags: stream, apache-flink, complex-event-processing, esper, dataflow

## groupwin

I use the meaning in esper:

> This view groups events into sub-views by the value returned by the specified expression or the combination of values returned by a list of expressions.

I think it is that you have the ability to operate by group,not stream(the group by is used to control how aggregations are grouped.)

## unaligned window

In google's dataflow ,unaligned windows means:

> By unaligned windows, we mean windows which do not span the entirety of a data source, but instead only a subset of it, such as per-user windows.

And does these mean the same thing?
`Set<event> XXXX = eventStream.GroupByKey(XXX);`

Answer (score 0):

Grouped windows: there is no relationship to aggregations and aggregations are operating only by the group-by clause if there is one. Grouped window for Esper is a way to define the subsets of events that are considered. That is useful various use cases, for example match-recognize pattern matching over a subset of events or just running some function over some subset of events or comparing previous events in the same group with "prev".

In general ability to "operate per-group" in Esper is done by contexts ie. context partition per key.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498805/how-to-describe-this-complex-scene-by-cep
In context,I can not do like that:EventA.context.paritionA.FieldB == EventB.context.paritionB.FieldE.
I can not do the correlation between two context's patititon.

Any way,how do you think about that context (patition per key) and the unaligned window? Are they the same thing?

Comment: Contexts and context partitions actually come from the book Event Processing in Action (see the docs). So the book would probably answer this. I don't know Google Dataflow. Each context partition is independent of others and can have its own lifetime. So going across context partitions is not a thing. Context partitions can be anything aligned or unaligned and they are not windows because they don't necessarily retain events.

Comment: Thanks you very much.it seems that I have to key by the stream before I pass it to the cep engine. By the way,groupwin() group seems OK,but it seems cannot be used in pattern